# Using cbind for explanatory variables in glmer in R

Tags: r, glm, lme4, cbind

I am trying to create a model in R where I want to estimate the variance of a particular ratio (in this example, nC:nT) of an individual that can be explained by the ratio of these values of its parents. In the model, I am using cbind for both the dependent and independent variables. The current generalised linear mixed effect model looks similar to this:

```
glmer(cbind(nC_offspring,nT_offspring) ~ cbind(nC_mother, nT_mother) + cbind(nC_father, nT_father) + (1|variable1) + (1|variable2), family = binomial)
```

The problem I am running into is that the results of the model of the cbind fixed effects, such as the estimates and p-values, are split up between nC and nT. i.e. I am getting estimates of nC_mother, nT_mother, nC_father and nT_father separately. In an ideal situation, I want the cbind ratio to be treated as a single factor, giving me the estimates of the cbind of the mother and of the father. I have been browsing around and cannot find a way to change the data so that the output of the glmer gives me these desired estimates. Does anybody have an idea how I can work around this? Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: why can't you just calculate the ratio by creating another column, `mother_ratio = nC_mother / nT_mother` and regress against that? The `cbind()` is only useful for your dependent variable